Skip to main content link on the Meta Stack Exchange header
Randomly, I encountered a "Skip to main content" link on the Meta Stack Exchange header.
Clicking on it redirects to https://meta.stackexchange.com/#content and hides the Meta site bar.


I initially thought it was a UI glitch, but upon inspecting the element, I noticed the "Skip to main content" link in the first header.

Was a partial code push made as part of an upcoming feature?

@Carrott good to see work here! While you're working on this, could you also take a look at this related request to turn on keyboard shortcuts if someone is tabbing around?

How do you get this to appear? When I inspect the element, it says it's a 1x1 element.

@Barmar After the page loads press tab a few times (it showed up for me after the 2nd press).

For what it's worth I noticed this thing a while ago but at the time it was a floating pop-up. It looks like it was changed at some point to be some kind of full-width button.

The Skip Link works as an anchor link to the content section of the page. Any element relatively positioned above the content section will be pushed up by the native browser behavior, locking into the #content fragment identifier.
To that end, we are marking this one as status by design.
